# Android HTTP GET And POST SLow

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I'm using android volley and my httppost and gets are taking a while to execute or dont execute, 10 + seconds.  I cant figure out what is causing this and a solution to it.

Logcat:

```
05-16 17:13:42.237: D/RenderPolicy(30189): ViewRootImpl.enableHardwareAcceleration -> enableRenderPolicy
05-16 17:13:42.287: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x736e61706d792e),sn(),family 0,flags 4
05-16 17:13:42.287: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
05-16 17:13:42.287: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x736e61706d792e),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
05-16 17:13:42.287: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
05-16 17:13:42.287: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
05-16 17:13:42.808: D/libc(30189): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success

05-16 16:59:29.077: D/Volley(30189): [27527] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://mysitedomain.com 0x3ef6da79 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=12023], [size=78957], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
05-16 16:59:38.677: D/Volley(30189): [1] Request.finish: 21664 ms: [ ] http://mysitedomain.com 0x3ef6da79 NORMAL 1
```

UPDATE Added Android code for making my volley call:

```
String token = savedtokens;
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());  // this = context
    final String url = "http://mydomainsite/services/api/rest/json/?method=messages.inbox&api_key=kdjfk8374jdhfjdh&username="+loggedinusername+"&auth_token="+token+"";
    System.out.println("NOTIFICATION_____:" + url);
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
               url, null,
               new Listener<JSONObject>() {
          private String html;
        JSONArray river = null;
        private String guid;
        private String avatar_url;
        private String type;
        private String from_guid;
        private String description;
        private String time_created;
        private String addcommentline;



        @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              // response
              System.out.println("Wire___________:" + response);
              html ="";
                try {




                   try {
                        // Getting Array of Contacts
                        river = response.getJSONArray("result");


                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for(int i = 0; i < river.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = river.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (c.has("guid")) {
                                guid = c.getString("guid");                     
                             System.out.println("guid:"+guid); }

                            if (c.has("username")) {
                                username = c.getString("username");                     
                             System.out.println("username:"+username); }

                            if (c.has("avatar_url")) {
                                avatar_url = c.getString("avatar_url");                     
                             System.out.println("avatar_url:"+avatar_url); }

                            if (c.has("type")) {
                                type = c.getString("type");                     
                             System.out.println("type:"+type); }

                            if (c.has("from_guid")) {
                                from_guid = c.getString("from_guid");                   
                             System.out.println("from_guid:"+from_guid); }



                            if (c.has("description")) {
                                description = c.getString("description");                   
                             System.out.println("description:"+description); }

                            if (c.has("time_created")) {
                                time_created = c.getString("time_created");                     
                             System.out.println("time_created:"+time_created); }

                            if (c.has("guid")) {  
                                guid = c.getString("guid");                       
                             System.out.println("guid:"+guid); }



                        html = "<a href='http://mydomainsite.com/services/api/rest/json/?method=user.profile&username="+username+"&limit=1000&offset=0&loggedinusername="+loggedinusername+"&getuserphotos'>"+"<img src="+avatar_url+" style='border-radius:60px;vertical-align:middle;width:10%'>"+username +"</a>"+": "+ type+ "<br>"+html; 

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }     

                System.out.println("ITLOADED");

                String summary = "<html><body>+html+</body></html>";
             wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
            wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);



          }
      },
      new ErrorListener()
      {
           @Override 
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // error
              // Log.d("Error.Responser", error);
               System.out.println("Volley response2___________:" + error);
         }
      }
   ) {    

   };
   jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
   queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

Comment: Is that the real site name? This looks suspiciously like a DNS timeout issue. Are you running inside a real device or using an emulator?

Comment: no sorry thats not the real site name. Im using a real device... Another weird thing is if I connect to my wifi at the house instead of the verizons network it works super fast. But once I connect to the verizons network it goes snail speed...  All the other installed apps work fine and normal in both scenarios

Comment: Without seeing more code it is hard to tell. It could be that the server is doing something based on the headers your client is sending. Do you have control over the server or do you know whether this is a possibility?

Comment: I own the hosting and website... I added my android code for volley at the top of this post